# How do I map CMD (Command ⌘) to shift MacVim window

Tags: vim, cmd, mapping, key-bindings, nerdtree

I know that I can use ctrl+w to shift between different Vim windows. But how do I remap the CMD-key to replace ctrl+w in various way? I'm specifically looking to bind cmd with the arrow keys, so that I can shift to NERDTree easily with CMD+LeftArrow.     Appreciate the assistance.

I've tried to add the following to $MYVIMRC...

```
nmap <silent> <D-h> :wincmd h<CR>   // For going to NERDTree 
nmap <silent> <D-l> :wincmd l<CR>   // For going back to file I'm working on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the left-hand side of a mapping, `Command+Left` is written `<D-Left>`. With this and other issues fixed (see below), your mappings should look like this:

```
nnoremap <D-Left> <Cmd>wincmd h<CR>
nnoremap <D-Right> <Cmd>wincmd l<CR>
```

or, simply, like this:

```
nnoremap <D-Left> <C-w>h
nnoremap <D-Right> <C-w>l
```

Other issues:

- Recursive mappings (`nmap`) should be reserved to the rare situations where you want to *use another mapping in your mapping*. This is not the case, here, so `nnoremap` is the best choice.
- The mapped commands don't echo anything so `<silent>` is useless.
- Vim's comment leader is `"`, not `//`.
- You can't have comments on the same line as a mapping anyway, see `:help map-comments`.
- The newish `:help <Cmd>` is cleaner than using `:` in the right-hand side of a mapping.

Note that *these mappings only work in the MacVim GUI*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments and pointers.
The comments were only added in my post here at stack overflow, I use the " comment leader in the rest of my vimrc file! But thanks for pointing it out anyway... //YOUR SOLUTION: I tried both of your solutions, but unfortunately none worked.
I'm using MacVim (Custom Version 9.0.472 (174) specifically). After saving my vimrc file i quit MacVim and restarted it. I'm on an old MacBook Pro (Late 2012) but that shouldn't matter. //ALTERNATIVES?: Do you have any other recommendations. What do you use to jump around between windows within MacVim?

Comment: Well, I tried both suggestions before submitting my answer and both of them worked in v174.